# Driver for wireless card WNC-0301 (Level One) for XP 64 bit

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, drivers, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I looking for drivers for network wireless PCI card WNC-0301 of Level One for Windows XP 64 bit. The one I found on company's site is zipped with password. In short, do somebody know where to find this driver?

Comment: any luck? I'm trying the same for Windows 7 x64 :(

Comment: Where did you find the driver, was it on `http://download.level1.tw/level1/driver/` ?  Did you try to get the server 2003 driver or another one? (XP 64 bit is more like server 2003 light than it is XP). What is the hardware ID of the adapter ?