# Acer Aspire Timeline X 4830T - Quiet? Loud? In the middle?

Tags: fan, acer-aspire, noise

Has anyone used [this notebook](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/series/aspire-timelinex) in a quiet room while doing something CPU-intensive? If you have, I'd be interested in how quiet or loud you found the fan to be.

Looking for direct experience of this specific model (or a link to a review specifically calling out how loud or quiet the machine is, but it's fairly new and I haven't found any that did yet).

Comment: @downvoter, what's wrong with the question?

Comment: @random et. al.: If this question is "too localized," then a huge chunk of the un-closed questions on SU are as well. This question and answer will be relevant for anyone else wanting a quiet computer and looking at the Acer. It's *at least* as general as [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/119727/how-to-config-dlink-dsl-2640t-to-allow-access-from-dyndns-route-to-specific-port), or [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/274917/dell-inspiron-1525-internal-hard-drive-not-found), or [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/40095/driver-for-wireless-card-wnc-0301-level-one-for-xp-64-bit)

Comment: @random et. al.: I have certainly found this sort of information of *tremendous* value when searching for quiet PCs in the past. It's perfectly likely to be of use to someone else going forward; I certainly would have liked to have found one like it when I was doing my research on the machine.

Comment: You're asking for user reviews. Which does not fit the Q&A model of this site.

Comment: @random: No, I'm asking "How loud is it?" And the answer is "Fairly quiet." Because "loud" *can be* a subjective term, I'm following the six guidelines and asking that people with *specific knowledge* reply. (And that would be "not a real question" rather than "too localized" in any case, wouldn't it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now have one, and it's pretty quiet. Details:

- When the fan is on low, it's near-silent.
- When the fan is on higher, it's a definite whirr. Not a screech or a growl, just a whirr. Not intrusive at all, but it is there. In contrast, my old Samsung NC10 was near silent at all times (but it just had a little Atom N270 in it, no great surprise the fan in the 4830T would be a bit more powerful).
- The HDD is very quiet.
- When burning, the slimline DVD is very loud. But that's to be expected.
- When playing a video DVD, the DVD drive is fairly quiet. You'd hear it in the quiet parts of a movie, but not if there were any sigificant background music in the scene, and certainly not in an action flick. (And the 4830T's speakers are very good indeed for such a unit, more than capable of overpowering the sound of the DVD drive.)

Answer (score 0):

I used one Acer Timeline X 4820, thats quite similar in features. I used for 2 weeks, and i can assure you will like it in terms the features you are interested. The fan noise is quite silent under high processor demand times and Core i3 M350 is such powerfull as enought for actual softwares.

Comment: Thanks. The 4830T is apparently part of a redesigned range, though, so while one hopes they won't have mucked things up, when I hear "redesign" I think "can't compare with previous models". It may be mostly aesthetic, though. Also uses a different processor, but it's in the same class (i3 2310M rather than the i3 M350). Thanks again,